# What can we tell about quadratic residues modulo $an+b$ ($n=1,2,\dots$)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I only know a little about quadratic residues, and I have a question that: What can we say about quadratic residues modulo $an+b$, for example, $30n+1$? $(n=1,2,\dots)$

Of course, $0,1,4,9,16,25$ are quadratic resiudes modulo $30n+1$ for all $n$.
However, $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $31$ while it is not a quadratic residue modulo $61$.
Are there any relations between quadratic residues modulo $30n+1$?
(For example, a statement such as $cn+d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $30n+1$.)

Comment: What can we say about quadratic residues modulo $n$ itself as $n$ varies? This is already a complicated question since $n$ is allowed to be composite. My instinct is that restricting the modulus to an arithmetic progression is relatively easy to incorporate, if we can answer the global question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment: we can find a family of x such that :

$x^2\equiv (cn+t)\bmod (3n+1)$

With some conditions. we must have:

$x^2=m(30n +1)+cn+d=n(30m+c)+m+d$

Suppose $m+d=t^2$ we have:

$(x-t)(x+t)=n(30m+c)$

Suppose:

$\begin{cases}x-t=n\\x+t=30m+c\end {cases}$

We get following conditions:

$\begin{cases} m+d=t^2\\x=\frac 12(30m +n+c)\\t=\frac 12(30m+c-n)\end{cases}$

which leads to solving  a system of Diophantine equation. For example :

for$m=1, n=2, c=4$ we get:

$x=18$

$30n+1=61$

$18^2\equiv 19\bmod 61$

$cn+d=4\times 2+d=19\rightarrow d=11$

$m+d=1+11=12$

Or another example:

which does not meet the condition $m+d=t^2$

But for $m=4$, $n=2$ and $c=6$ we get:

$x=64$

$64^2\equiv 9\bmod 61$

$9=2\times 6-3\Rightarrow d=-3$

$\Rightarrow m+d =4-3=1=1^2$

So residue is $cn+d=6n-3$

That is for particular magnitudes of n there exist numbers like x such that the quadratic residue is of the form $cn+d$.

To find n, m and c  may be a good computer program can give us many residues in form of $cn+d$.